# Ant move function with replace?

Tags: ant

I move files using Ant move function.
I want that token #COUNTER# in files was replaced by another token during moving this files.

I know that the Ant copy function allows to copy with replace. Can the move function do this?   If not, is there some workaround?

Comment: i want to do this in the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ant tasks [copy](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) and [move](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) behave the same when using [filters](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html) to replace tokens. They both support the filtering attribute.

But you can also call the [replace](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task yourself after you copied/moved the files.

Example (from the doc):

```
<replace dir="${src}" value="VALUE">
  <include name="**/*.html"/>
  <replacetoken>#COUNTER#</replacetoken>
</replace>
```